# Use Random from multiple variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, random

In a function, I have a statement like this.

```
 Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'spikes' : 'slime'
```

I want to add one more variable and let the program randomly choose one of those 3. Lets call it 'stone'
How do I change the statement to randomly choose one of the three?
I do not want to use arrays to do this.
Any help would be appreciated. 
This is part of an open source code and I am a beginner hence getting difficulties in understanding.

Comment: `var random = Math.random()` and then use `if`/`else` chain to choose the result (if you only want three or maybe four things) or alternatively `switch` (any number).

Comment: Use if else if else

Comment: *"I do not want to use arrays to do this"* - Why not? It's the most straight forward way to do it. If you don't want the most straight forward way, there are infinite ways to make it more difficult, but why would you?

Comment: Array sampling would be the best way to approach this.

Comment: This is the function. When I put the array inside, it doesnt run

function spawnEnemySprites() {
      if (score > 100 && Math.random() > 0.96 && enemies.length < 3 && platformLength > 5 &&
      (enemies.length ? canvas.width - enemies[enemies.length-1].x >= platformWidth * 3 ||
       canvas.width - enemies[enemies.length-1].x < platformWidth : true)) {
    enemies.push(new Sprite(
      canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed,
      platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer - platformWidth,
   
      Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'spikes' : 'slime' 
    ));
  }
}

Comment: If you have a specific issue with specific code, post that code into the question. Don't ask wide-reaching questions around it which make little sense. Typical XY problem.

Answer (score 4):

Array is the best option:

```js
var result = ['spikes', 'slime', 'stone'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

console.log(result);
```

switch/case would be a passable option, although you can see the amount of code needed vs. the one with the array:

```js
function getRandom() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  switch (num) {
    case 0:
      return 'spikes';

    case 1:
      return 'slime';

    default:
      return 'stone';
  }

}

console.log(getRandom());
```

Comment: I would inline the random number generation into the `switch (...)`, but that's a minor quibble…

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. He (op user) wants to access variables declared in a scope.

Comment: @Someone Wut? Where'd you get that idea from?

Comment: @deceze Firstly, I don't agree with the idea of the op objective, but this answer doesn't answer it, it's only recommending to use something ("objects").

Comment: @Someone That's the impression the title gives, but the example uses simple strings, I think the op is simply confusing their terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are the most fluent approach. Simply have an array with the available options and sample it.

```js
Array.prototype.sample = function() {
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
}

// example without dirtying Array.prototype
function sampleArray(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

var array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'];

document.write([array.sample(), sampleArray(array)].join('<br />'));
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Someone I think you're seriously misunderstanding what *is* actually being asked here, and you should fix that before downvoting everyone.

Comment: @deceze But I'm always downvoted when I answer a question better than others. That's why I didn't answer this question. I reply correctly. The op title means "variables", not "objects", or related-thing.

Comment: @Someone And now you're *really* conflating issues…

Comment: @Someone Don't downvote others because you get downvoted. I read the question and I feel my answer addresses it properly.

Comment: I, on the other hand, think this answer is correct, but I'd propose a minor improvement `Math.ceil(Math.random() * arr.length) % arr.length` -> `Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)`

Comment: I keep forgetting how to play with random efficiently, I always mix up when what goes, haha. Updated the answer, thank you